# Creating "Comment" instances in Django for migration?

Tags: python, django, comments, django-comments

I currently have a bunch of old comments, that I need to migrate to `django.contrib.comment` and the plan was to manually create instances of Comment and then save it as follows:

```
# assume some_content is NOT a django Comment instance, but in some proprietary format
# assume the model I'm attaching the comment to is called Blog i.e models.Blog
c = Comment()
c.user = user
c.submit_date = some_comment.comment_date_time
c.comment = some_comment.comment
... 
c.save()
```

The main issue is the missing information found in class `BaseCommentAbstractModel` found in `django.contrib.comment.model`. Specifically the three fields:

```
BaseCommentAbstractModel(models.Model):
    # Content-object field
    content_type   = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s")
    object_pk      = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
```

I read the documentation and, to the best of my ability, the source, but it wasn't detailed enough. How do I properly specify those fields from the model object (model.Blog)?

Maybe there is a method somewhere that accepts model object and the content of the comment to add?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/):

- set the **content_type** to an instance of **ContentType** of your model (the one you're attaching the comment to):

  `content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Blog)`
- set **object_pk** to the primary key of your object:

  `object_pk = myBlog_instance.pk`
- **content_object** will point to these 2 fields, you dont have to set it.